# Control not found in the code behind of an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages, code-behind

I have this code in **InfoEdition.aspx** :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Espace_Candidat/SousCandidat.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InfoEdition.aspx.cs" Inherits="Espace_Candidat_InfoEdition" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ChildContent2" Runat="Server">
<div class="span9">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

In the code behind **InfoEdition.aspx.cs** when i try to access to the textbox :

```
public partial class Espace_Candidat_InfoEdition : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// THE TEXTBOX IS NOT FOUND
      TextBox1.
    }
}
```

the textbox is not found!!!

- What are the reasons of this error?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution. Is this a web site or a web application?

Comment: Have you tried to view this in the browser rather than rely on the Visual Studio intellisense - it can sometimes not update

Comment: it is a web application

Comment: please give us the full code for the code-behind page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using `var txt1 = Content1.FindControl("TextBox1")` and then if the `txt1` is not null use it as you would normally use `TextBox1` ?

```
var txt1 = Content1.FindControl("TextBox1");
txt1.Text = "some value";
```

Comment: It's great that this works, but accessing it by "Textbox1" really should work too.  I'd watch carefully for other errors as you might run in  other places later because of whatever is causing this issue.

Comment: When its a sub control you cant just access it, you have to access it via the parents control collection like I've shown above. Or at least I always have had to do that when I add controls to a `Content, Repeater,DataView/DataGrid/GridView` control.

Comment: This doesn't look like a sub control though. It's placed directly on the page. There should have been a strongly typed field created for it in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Change `CodeFile` to `Codebehind` in the declarations.

**UPDATED**
Check the "Build Action" property of the InfoEdition.aspx page set to? It should be set to "Content".

Comment: Can you access the Content1 control?

Comment: Also, what namespace (if any) is wrapping the code in the codebehind?  You may need to add it to the "Inherits" property like "Mynamespace.Espace_Candidat_InfoEdition".

Comment: no namespace is exist and i can't acces to content1

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit late, but one of the things you could do is the check if the designer file exists in the folder where your ASPX page is.

If the designer file is missing, code-behind cannot find your fields.

In order to recreate the designer field, you'll need to rebuild it using the 
**VS2019** Project --> Convert to Web Application menu option